# Subset Json object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, subset, slice

Given an array of json object like this below, (the json object such as "name2" and "name4" will definitely have only one key-value)

```
[
  {
    abc: 123,
    id: '18263322',
    name: 'name1'
  },
  { name: 'name2' },
  {
    abc: 456,
    id: '18421634',
    name: 'name3'
  },
  { name: 'name4' }
]
```

How can I subset this so that I have two array of json objects:

```
[
  {
    abc: 123,
    id: '18263322',
    name: 'name1'
  },
  {
    abc: 456,
    id: '18421634',
    name: 'name3'
  }
]
```

and

```
[
  { name: 'name2' },
  { name: 'name4' }
]
```

Comment: What do you want exactly? Can you explain more your question? Thank

Comment: use `Array.prototype.reduce`

Comment: I would like to split the first array (in the first code section) in to two array of json. I use this code: ```data = [
  {
    abc: 123,
    id: '18263322',
    name: 'name1'
  },
  { name: 'name2' },
  {
    abc: 456,
    id: '18421634',
    name: 'name3'
  },
  { name: 'name4' }
]

data.filter(function(x) {
            console.log(Object.keys(x).length !== 1);
        });``` This gets me true and false but not the array itself, and it seems very slow to process

Comment: @SunTianyi Since you have tried so you should include it in the question itself. So that other people can understand what have you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) here

```js
const arr = [
  {
    abc: 123,
    id: "18263322",
    name: "name1",
  },
  { name: "name2" },
  {
    abc: 456,
    id: "18421634",
    name: "name3",
  },
  { name: "name4" },
];

const [single, multiple] = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    Object.keys(curr).length === 1 ? acc[0].push(curr) : acc[1].push(curr);
    return acc;
  },[[], []]
);

console.log(single);
console.log(multiple);
```

You can also do something like

```
const [single, multiple] = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[Object.keys(curr).length === 1 ? 0 : 1].push(curr);
    return acc;
  },[[], []]);
```

using filter

```js
const arr = [
  {
    abc: 123,
    id: "18263322",
    name: "name1",
  },
  { name: "name2" },
  {
    abc: 456,
    id: "18421634",
    name: "name3",
  },
  { name: "name4" },
];

const single = arr.filter((o) => Object.keys(o).length === 1);
const multiple = arr.filter((o) => Object.keys(o).length !== 1);

console.log(single);
console.log(multiple);
```

Comment: That works like a charm! I thought about ```Object.keys(x).length``` but never thought about reduce. Thank you so much!

Comment: @SunTianyi Added solution with filter also. Have a look

Comment: Do you mind commenting on which one is more efficient? I think the reduce is more efficient because it seems like only looping through once? whereas the second method does two filters loops @decpk

Comment: You shouldn't consider the efficient solution if the dataset is small. If it would have millions of records then I would go with reduce since it takes a single loop to filter the data.

Comment: Thanks for your advise! I was asking the efficiency because I have maybe ten thousands of records.